# console.debug não está funcionando no Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Estou usando a versão `58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)` do navegador (a ultima disponível aqui ao criar essa pergunta), e ao tentar executar o seguinte código:

```
console.debug("Teste", 1);
```

O resultado é apenas:

```
undefined
```

E nada é impresso na tela.

Chrome:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo código funciona normalmente nos outros navegadores.

Firefox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

IE:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse é o resultado esperado: https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger

Comment: Sim, mas ele não está imprimindo a mensagem pedida, apesar do returno `undefined`. Editei a pergunta adicionando imagens.

Comment: Eles mudaram os filtros, no combo onde está escrito "Info" na screenshot você pode escolher o nivel do log, se colocar ele como "Verbose" as mensagens do `console.debug` aparecem, mas eu diria para usar o `console.log` mesmo

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa só converter em resposta que eu aceito, haha... Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na ultima versão do Chrome foram feitas algumas mudanças nos filtros do console.

Agora ele possui uma combo com as opções de nível de log, por padrão ele vem como `Info`, o que esconde qualquer log criado por chamadas ao `console.debug()`, para exibir estes logs só precisa alterar o nível para `Verbose`.

[image: Exemplo de uso]

Comment: Excelente +1, eu adicionei a imagem para tornar mais intuitivo.

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.log`. `console.debug` é uma alias de `console.log`.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#consoledebugobject_object